# Php version mismatch while upgrading laravel project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to upgrade laravel `5.4` to `5.6`.

I am getting following error:

Problem 1

```sh
This package requires php >=7.1.3 but your PHP version (5.6.37;
Package overridden via config.platform
(actual: 7.3.6)) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Problem 2

```sh
laravel/framework v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version
(7.3.6) overridden by "config.platform
.php" version (5.6.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not upgrade to the latest version of Laravel: 5.8

Comment: I'd have thought "requires php ^7.1.3" gives you quite an obvious clue about how to fix it? To be clear...you need to install PHP 7.1.3 or above

Answer (score 1):

What is your current PHP version?
It seems like you have PHP 5.6.
Starting version 5.5 Laravel requires PHP 7+
You can upgrade your PHP version in order to solve this issue, However, you need to make sure that the rest of your code is PHP 7 compatible.